# Bash form with two columns

Tags: forms, dialog

This script creates a form in a terminal window with one column and four rows. How can I create a form with two columns and two rows?

```
shell=""
groups=""
user=""
home=""
exec 3>&1
VALUES=$(dialog --ok-label "Submit" \
          --title "Useradd" \
          --form "User form" \
15 50 0 \
        "Username:" 1 1 "$user"         1 10 10 0 \
        "Shell:"    2 1 "$shell"        2 10 10 0 \
        "Group:"    3 1 "$groups"       3 10 10 0 \
        "HOME:"     4 1 "$home"         4 10 10 0 \
2>&1 1>&3)

exec 3>&-
```

This script produces:

[image: a form with one column and four rows]

I would prefer this arrangement of the input fields:

[image: a form with two columns and two rows]

I have tried to add a second `--form` option, but it didn't work. 
I also have tried to add a second input field on the same row, but starting after the first, like this:

```
    "Second field:" 1 41 "$second"      1 10 10 0 \
```

It creates two headers, on the same row, but only one input field – on the next row.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding the man page you could also check [this](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_form_dialog_for_input). Which does have an information about how the fields are defined `[ label y x item y x flen ilen ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the man page for `dialog`,
you’ll see that you must specify the Y and X coordinates for the fields
*and also, independently, for the field labels.* 
In your unsuccessful attempt,
you moved the label into a (potential) second column,
but you left the field in the first column. 
I changed the field definition block to

```
            "Username:" 1  1 "$user"         1 10 10 0 \
            "Shell:"    2  1 "$shell"        2 10 10 0 \
            "Group:"    1 25 "$groups"       1 34 10 0 \
            "HOME:"     2 25 "$home"         2 34 10 0 \
```

(note that I’ve increased both the field X coordinate
and the label X coordinate for “Group:” and “HOME:”). 
This produces

[image: dialog form with two columns and two rows]

which is essentially what you asked for.